# How to get Emails List directly from MailChimp using MailChimp.Net.V3

Tags: c#, .net

I´ve been trying to get a list of sent emails using MailChimp.Net.V3 in .NET 7 MVC but the only thing that I was sucesseful was getting a user to be subscribed to  newsletter.

Has anyone tried this or know if it is even possible to get  the List of sent emails for newsletter?

GitHub of the MailChimp.Net.V3:
https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net

Tried to get list of emails using MailChimp.Net.V3 and not even ChatGPT helped.